# unmark Question as a Duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

How can I have a question unmarked as a duplicate?

I have had two questions now which have been incorrectly marked as a duplicate. I have explained clearly in my response why they are different, especially where the so-called duplicate question hasn’t been successfully answered, and the responses are dated.

I think that incorrectly marking a question as a duplicate devalues the process, and makes it difficult to move the question forward.

What is the mechanism for fixing this? The message says “please edit this question”, but that doesn’t seem to help.

Comment: I think you should ask this on meta.SO (or the meta of the site your questions lie in), not here. Also don't forget to put there more details. (Links to your question, comments etc.)